# Which theorem should be used to solve this question?

Tags: geometry, triangles

My friend sent me that question and said "another Carnot theorem" is used to solve this question but i couldnt find that theorem. Can you help me?

Additional explanation: 
$$ \widehat{ABD} = 30^{\circ} $$
$$ \widehat{DBC} = 1^{\circ} $$
$$ \widehat{ACD} = 89^{\circ} $$
$$ \widehat{BAD}  =  \widehat{DAC} $$ 
$$ x(\widehat{BCD}) = ? $$

[image: Hard geometry question]

Comment: You are asking the length of $BC$? Also, what are the angles $ACD, DCB, DBC$? they are $89, x(?),1(!?)$?

Comment: argh, i need to explain question more. BAD and DAC angles are equal. Question wants x angle (BCD)

Comment: I feel some difficulty to read your letter. ACD=89, DBC=1?

Comment: Yes, you read them right.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Which theorem should be used to solve this question?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Ceva's theorem (in trigonometric form -- http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml)

We have

$\frac{\sin 1^\circ\sin 89^\circ}{\sin 30^\circ\sin x}=1$, i. e.

$sin x = \frac{\sin 1^\circ \cos 1^\circ}{\sin 30^\circ} = 2 \sin 1^\circ \cos 1^\circ=sin 2^\circ$

$x=2^\circ$

Comment: Thank you :) My friend told me wrong theorem, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Take $E$ - reflection of $C$ about $AD$, it belongs to $AB$ and $\widehat{BED}=91^\circ$, i.e. $O$, the circumcenter of $\triangle BDE$ belongs to $BC$ and $BO=OD=DE=CD$, hence $\widehat{BCD}=\widehat{COD}=2^\circ$.

Best regards